# Regex only captures the last occurrence of a match in html format

Tags: html, regex

I've been learning regex and for that I have been working on Hackerrank problems. I came across a problem where I am asked to remove html format and only keep whatever is inside an anchor tag's reference (the value of the href part), and the text inside the tag, then present this separated by a comma.

I came up with the following code to extract such information:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String line = s.nextLine();

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)<a href=\"([^\"]+)\"([^<>]*)>(<\\w+>)*([^<>]+)</a>(</\\w+>)*");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(2).trim() + "," + m.group(5).trim());
            }
        }
}
```

This code, when presented with cases such as `<p><a href="folder/page" id="link">text</a></p>` Passes and outputs `folder/page,text`

But if the input has multiple `<a>` tags, it will only grab the last occurrence of it and output that, instead of outputting all possible matches for that single input. Why is this happening? Please don't feel obliged to answer my question fully if you think I can answer it myself with just a hint. Thank you for any answers in advance

Comment: That's because you are being *greedy* i.e, using `(.*)`

Comment: Thank you so much! More cases passed as I added the `?`. I'll keep working to see what I can change to pass them all